# Emitting an array using socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, p5.js

For a school project I'am making a multiplayer snake game with socket.io. I tried to sync the body of the snake you play (snake1, which is an array with vectors as location. The snakes them self are objects) and send that with socket.io to the other player. To send the body I use `socket.emit('snakeBody', snake1.body)`. But when I load the page i get the error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". I first thought it was the array but when i try to sync a normal variable with a vector i still got the error (when i sync normal variables or arrays, without a vector in it, it does work). My question is if it is possible to sync an array with a vectors as values using socket.io.

The index.js file (the file where all the socket things happen):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log("The server is live");

var socket = require('socket.io');
var io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', newConnection);

function newConnection(socket) {
  socket.on('snakeBody', body);

  function body(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('testBody', data);
  }
}
```

The game.js file (the base of the game. Where the socket sends and receives)

```
//Defines both snakes
var snake1;
var snake2;

var socket;

function setup() {
  //The canvas for p5js to show something
  createCanvas(400, 400);

  //The starting location for the snakes (the snakes are objects in a class)
  snake1 = new Snake(200, 200);
  snake2 = new Snake(150, 250);

  //Socket server ip
  socket = io.connect('https://myIP.com');
  socket.on('snakeBody', newSnake);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);

  snake1.loop(255, 0, 0, 1, 340);

  //Sends all the players data to the server to be send to the other player
  socket.emit('snakeBody', snake1.body);
}


function newSnake(newSnake) {
  //The function that will do thing when it receives something from the socket
}
```

The snake class:
It is possible that it will call function that do not exist in this part but thats because I removed them because they were not directly important for this question.

```
class Snake {

  //----------------------------------------------//
  //                 Snake Setup:                 //
  //----------------------------------------------//

  //Contains all building info
  constructor(x, y) {
    //Snake elements:
    this.body = [];
    this.body[0] = createVector(x, y);
    this.head = '';
    this.part = '';

    //Game elements:
    //Dimension
    this.dim = 10;
    //Direction 
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    //Speed 
    this.s = 2;
    //Score
    this.scoreLeng = 0;
  }

  //Contains all functions that needs to be looped
  loop(r, g, b, p, t) {
    //Move and update
    this.move(p);
    this.update();

    //If snake is dead
    if (this.gameOver()) {
      //Respawn
      this.respawn(p);
    }

    //If snake eat
    if (this.eat(food)) {
      //Grow
      this.grow();
      //Update food location
      food.update();
      //Play eat sound
      // eatSound.play();
    }
    //Show snake
    this.show(r, g, b, t);
  }

  //----------------------------------------------//
  //            All snake functions:              //
  //----------------------------------------------//

  show(r, g, b, t) {
    //Loop thru every body part of array
    for (var i = 0; i < this.body.length; i++) {
      //Rectangle with rgb color:
      fill(r, g, b);
      noStroke();
      rect(this.body[i].x, this.body[i].y, this.dim, this.dim);
    }
    //Score text:
    textSize(17);
    text("score:" + this.scoreLeng, t, 395);
  }

  dir(x, y) {
    //Directions:
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  update() {
    //Copy of the last element of the array:
    this.head = this.body[this.body.length - 1].copy();
    //Shift the array
    this.body.shift();

    //Add direction to snake location
    this.head.x += this.x;
    this.head.y += this.y;

    //Push head to end of array
    this.body.push(this.head);
  }

  gameOver() {
    //If snake is outside play area 
    if (this.head.x == 400 || this.head.y == 400 || this.head.x < 0 || this.head.y < 0) {
      return true;
    }

    //Loop thru body parts in array
    for (var i = 0; i < this.body.length - 1; i++) {
      //Alle body parts in part variable
      this.part = this.body[i];
      //If head of snake hits part
      if (this.part.x == this.head.x && this.part.y == this.head.y) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    //Loop thru body array
    for (var j = 0; j < this.body.length - 1; j++) {
      //If snake 1 or snake 2 head hits parts of other snake
      if (snake1.head.x == this.body[j].x && snake1.head.y == this.body[j].y) {
        console.log("snake 1 is dead");
      }
      if (snake2.head.x == this.body[j].x && snake2.head.y == this.body[j].y) {
        console.log("snake 2 is dead");
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: try `toString()` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a `Maximum call stack size exceeded" error, it means that somewhere in your code, you are calling a function which in turn calls another function and so forth, until you hit the call stack limit. I'm not sure how that would apply in your case here, you're not sharing much.

My quick suggestion for you would be to send your data as string:

```
socket.emit('snakeBody', JSON.stringify(snake1.body))
```

Then on the other end, parse it:

```
const snakeBody = JSON.parse(snakeBody)
```

Comment: The JSON.stringify did not work. I added my code in the main question. Maybe that can help you solve my problem

Comment: @The_Lazy_Trutle I would need to see your `Snake` class. No need to share your server code.

Comment: Added the snake class

Comment: @The_Lazy_Trutle Since you only have one element in the body, try this instead `socket.emit('snakeBody', JSON.stringify(snake1.body[0]))` or with P5: `socket.emit('snakeBody', snake1.body[0].toString())`

Comment: @The_Lazy_Trutle It's working fine for me ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Its working because i just changed it.the .toString() help solve the stack error. I now have different problems but i think i can solve those my self. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @The_Lazy_Trutle You're welcome. Btw, feel free to upvote too.